# How to insert the dynamic table row data into database at once

Tags: php, mysql

This is my html codes for dynamic table rows. This duplicate the table fields by clicking the Add new button. The problem is I cannot insert all the filled data into the database. It would be nice if you can help me. Thanks a lot.

```
 <!-- Time&Task -->

                    <div class="box-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"></label>
                      <div class="col-sm-10">

                       <br>
        <table class="table table-striped" id="maintable" width="50%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="pdzn_tbl1" border="0px">
        <tr>
                <th>Time Start:</th>
                <th>Time End:</th>
                <th>Task:</th>
                <th>Comment:</th>
        </tr>

        <tr class="rows"> 
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="time" name="item[0][timestart]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="time" name="item[0][timeend]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[0][tasks]" />
            </td>
            <td style="padding:5px;">
                <input type="text" name="item[0][comment]" />
            </td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <div id="add_new">ADD NEW</div>


    <?php
if (isset($_POST['item']) && is_array($_POST['item'])) {
    $items = $_POST['item'];
    $i = 0;
    foreach($items as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Item '.$i++.': '.$value['timestart'].' '.$value['timeend'].' '.$value['tasks'].' '.value['comment'].'<br />';
    }
}
?>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div><!-- /.box-body -->
```

---

This is my sql query for inserting. here is the problem. I don't know how to loop to insert into the DB. Thanks. :D

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['data']) && !empty($_POST['data'])) {

     $timestart = htmlspecialchars($_POST['timestart']);
     $timeend = htmlspecialchars($_POST['timeend']);
     $tasks = htmlspecialchars($_POST['tasks']);
     $comment = htmlspecialchars($_POST['comment']);

  include('DBConnect.php');


       $SQL = "INSERT INTO TSTable (timestart,timeend,tasks,comment) VALUES ('$timestart','$timeend','$tasks','$comment')";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $SQL)) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
} 
     }
```

---

**! Hi all, I found a solution already. Here are the correct codes. I hope it helps someone who needs it. 
The html is still the same and only sql query part needed to fix.**

---

```
if (isset($_POST['data'])) {

     $timestart = $_POST['timestart'];
     $timeend = $_POST['timeend'];
     $tasks = $_POST['tasks'];
     $comment = $_POST['comment'];

  include('DBConnect.php');

$count= count($timestart);
for ($i=0; $i< $count; $i++){
    if($timestart[$i] != null ||  !empty($timestart[$i])){

       $SQL = "INSERT INTO TSTable (timestart,timeend,tasks,comment) VALUES ( '$timestart[$i]','$timeend[$i]','$tasks[$i]','$comment[$i]')";    
}
if (mysqli_query($conn, $SQL)) {

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
}  

     }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11483799/php-mysql-dynamic-prepared-statement-with-insert-update-query

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things here that will make your life easier if changed.

Input elements with the same name will be submitted as an array, in the order they appear. Standard procedure is to layout your html like so (a few fields removed for brevity);

```
<td><td><input name=timestart><input name=timeend><input name=tasks></td></tr>
<td><td><input name=timestart><input name=timeend><input name=tasks></td></tr>
<td><td><input name=timestart><input name=timeend><input name=tasks></td></tr>
... etc
```

This will give you a post structure such as ;

```
Array
(
[timestart] => Array
    (
        [0] => timestart 1
        [1] => timestart 2
        [2] => timestart 3
    )

[timeend] => Array
    (
        [0] => timeend 1
        [1] => timeend 2
        [2] => timeend 3
    )

[task] => Array
    (
        [0] => task 1
        [1] => task 2
        [2] => task 3
));
```

And insert with;

```
$timestart = $_POST['timestart'];
$timeend = $_POST['timeend'];
$task = $_POST['task'];

for($i=1 ; $i < count($timestart) ; $i++)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO TSTable VALUES($timestart[$i],$timeend[$i],$task[$i]);"
    ... more code goes here..
}
```

Comment: Hi. Still not working. Thanks for the answer though. :D

Comment: When is `Input elements with the same name will be submitted as an array, in the order they appear. ` true?

Comment: @chris85 that's what happens when someone tries to use code that doesn't work, eh? ;-)