# For loop only firing once, inputting incorrect values into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

First off, I know that there is deprecated code in my example, I'm working with a platform I designed a while ago and have not yet finished updating it all to use mysqli instead, so I'm making some minor edits to the existing platform.

So I have a form that creates inputs based on categories inputted in a different table, the form outputs correctly but repeats the same name (points and cat) for each category that exists.

According to another post ([How to insert the dynamic table row data into database at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469080/how-to-insert-the-dynamic-table-row-data-into-database-at-once])) inserting this data into my table can be accomplished with a for loop as shown in my example.

The issue I'm having is that it's only firing once, despite the fact that the array it creates should have 4 inputs. Also, the data that is being sent to the table column "cat_id" is "3" which could either be the first digit of the cat_id it's using, or the last array iteration [0], [1], [2], [3].

This is my first question, so I apologize if all the details needed are not provided, I will gladly update if anything else is needed.

```
$cat_id     = $_POST['cat'];
$points     = $_POST['points'];

$count      = count($cat_id);

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    $sql    = "INSERT INTO scoring (cat_id, points) VALUES ('$cat_id[$i]','$points[$i]')";
    $query = mysql_query($sql);

}
```

EDIT: Updated code based on suggestions.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if `mysql_real_escape_string` (please note **"string"**) would operate correctly on an array. In any case, the returned value (`$cat_id`) would be a string

Comment: Agree with @Phil. Pretty sure mysql_real_escape_**string** will return a boolean in this case, thus making `count` 1, thus firing the loop only once. Dump the values you're using and see what you get.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string` has been removed from both `$cat_id` and `$points`, the results are the same :(

Comment: array map may help you here such as `array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $points )` if the items are strings.  That function mysql_real_escape_string, should not be removed, that is the only thing preventing sql injection in your code.

Comment: Relying on two different arrays to have corresponding indexes seems a really bad idea

Comment: What exactly does your form look like?

Comment: The answer on that question is a terrible example. Arrays aren't auto built. ` $_POST['cat']` is probably a string. `var_dump( $_POST['cat'])` and see what it is. This code is dangerous and allows SQL injections.

Comment: chris it Could be  `<input name="cat[]" type="checkbox" value="books" />` for example, in which case the input is not sent with the form is submitted  when the checkbox is not checked, which is most likely the issue.

Comment: The form has 2 related fields. `<input type='hidden' name='cat' value='" . $data_cat['cat_id'] . "' />` to pass the category id of each category, and `<input name='points' type='number' step='any' min='0' max ='" . $data_cat['max_pts'] . "' />` for the points.

Comment: queries run in loops are a bad idea, you should build the query in the loop but execute it outside

Comment: Also, `array_map` is returning an error, looks like an array is not being created. Back to the drawing board I go. Thanks all!

Comment: @SeanStapleton - as others have stated, var_dump() that field and see, what kind of input in the form and what is the name, does it have `[]` in the name for example?  if not then it's probably not an array, php will interpret the ones with brackets as an array.  others, not so much.

Comment: That question's answer you looked at under http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33469080/how-to-insert-the-dynamic-table-row-data-into-database-at-once you should have looked at the link I left in there in a comment for it and have looked at the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483987/ rather than one the other guy said it didn't work.

Comment: `var_dump` of `$points`inside the for loop shows a string, outside the for loop shows `array(4) { [0]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(1) "2" [2]=> string(1) "3" [3]=> string(1) "4" }`

Comment: the question becomes then, why do you think it is doing only one iteration of the loop, because it makes one record?  That's not exactly the same thing.  On the other hand you are looping on $cat_id, so $points is generally irrelevant here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question/answer you linked are incorrect. Arrays are not built dynamically by default in HTML:

> To get your `<form>` result sent as an array to your PHP script you name the `<input>`, `<select>` or `<textarea>` elements like this:
>
> ```
>  <input name="MyArray[]" />
>  <input name="MyArray[]" />
>  <input name="MyArray[]" />
>  <input name="MyArray[]" />
> ```

http://php.net/manual/en/faq.html.php#faq.html.arrays

So I presume you currently have

```
<input name="cat">
<input name="cat">
```

which will only process as one `cat` element. This causes your 1 iteration.

Try:

```
<input name="cat[]">
```

for each field. To debug this in the future use `print_r` or `var_dump` to output what you think a variable contains.

Also use `mysql_real_escape` at a minimum while you update your driver to something that can handle parameterized queries.

Comment: or var_export(), to debug :P

Comment: I'm in here too http://stackoverflow.com/q/33469080/ lol as per a comment I left in there back in Nov. 2015

Comment: *"Also use mysql_real_escape at a minimum while you update your driver to something that can handle parameterized queries."* - They could use `(int)` or `intval()` instead, making it perfectly safe.

Comment: Good job there Chris ;-)

Comment: Yea, casting would work as well. Pretty much just never put user input directly into a query.